# excel pivot table with unique data so don't weant to see the count but the actual data

Tags: excel, pivot, counting

I have a csv file like this

```
| Date   |  PO |
|21-04-21|  A  |
|21-04-21|  B  |
|21-04-21|  C  |
|22-04-21|  B  |
|22-04-21|  C  |
|23-04-21|  B  |
|23-04-21|  D  |
```

atm, when I'm making a pivot table in excel, I'm getting the count number

```
   |21-04-21|22-04-21|23-04-21|
 A |   1    |    0   |   0    |
 B |   1    |    1   |   1    |
 C |   1    |    1   |   0    |
 D |   0    |    0   |   1    |
```

I'd like formatted this way since each row are unique:

```
 |21-04-21|22-04-21|23-04-21|
 |   A    |    B   |   B    |
 |   B    |    C   |   D    |
 |   C    |        |        |
```

Is it possible using a pivot table or I need another way to do so...
thks gorgeous people!!

Comment: You can Pivot with no aggregation in Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

Answer (score 0):

You can add a measure to show the information.

1. Make a table and create pivot from the table.
   Choose "Add this data to the Data Model". The table will be named `Table1`

[image]

2. Create a new measure for the pivot table.
   [image]
3. Then enter the following DAX formula:

   `=CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Table1[PO]),Table1[PO]," "))`

[image]

4. Then enter move the field as the picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll work on it to understand your magic... I wish there wasn't empty cell but I think I can do it not as elegantly like you.

Comment: I tried, but I don't think you can do it in an easy way. You'll have some kind of index on the Y axis and in this case I used PO. Maybe maybe it might work to do a custom group, but I think it's quite a lot of work and complexity.

Comment: Thanks again for your support I don't know how to express my problem in way some else could find your great tutorial on google (or else) to help more people...